# How to fix jagged edges of TImage

Tags: delphi, c++builder, firemonkey, antialiasing

I added an image in a FireMonkey Desktop App project.
If I rotate the image the edges become jagged.

How can I fix that?

I searched for AntiAliasing in RAD Studio XE5 but I didn't find any useful information.
Every geometric figure in the picture below is held in a separate TImage component.

The form is transparent.

[image: Jagged Edges]

Comment: Firemonkey is not going to AntiAlias any images. You have to do that to the original bitmaps before you put them in.

Comment: @DougRudd, that should be the answer.